# If I visit a place multiple times with the same Interrail pass, is it considered as a fraudulent "commuting" case?

Tags: trains, interrail

I have used Interrail passes of longer durations (2 or 3 months) to accomplish multiple trips with a hop back home in between. The limit of two in/outbound days is accommodated by purchasing local tickets in my country of residence for the additional travel to and from the border.

But, I am still unsure of another thing. The terms & conditions specify that commuting is not allowed using the pass.

I guess that a Swiss resident who purchases the 3-month continuous pass and uses it to commute daily between Basel and Mannheim, for instance, is fully targeted by this condition.

On the other hand, I can go to Berlin, do a quick hop to Hamburg, then Amsterdam, then back to Berlin, and continue elsewhere.

I can also plan to visit, for example, Amsterdam twice with one month between the two visits, because there are two separate festivals I would like to attend at different dates.

How can we reasonably set the limit? How to determine that the travel pattern does not enter the scope of the commuting case, which is considered improper use by the T&C?

Comment: How can visiting Amsterdam twice be considered to be 'commuting'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terms and conditions state that it's not intended for daily commuting to work or school. So repeated trips between nearby locations could be seen as improper use.
for longer trips with intervals for visits home, I'd recommend checking with Interrail's customer service to double-check your itinerary is in line with their rules and policies.